# Awesome WM can't seem to be able to find some programs in the right-click menu

Tags: awesome

Basically I can't find Skype or Spotify in the right click menu, where I can find all other applications I've installed.

I am looking for some way to be able to start them (even if it is through a search).

Note: I know I can start them from the console, but I am wondering if there is another way

Comment: either update whatever program you use to generate a menu (XDG menu? ) or add your new programs to the Awesome menu. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-menu . If you need further assistance, we need more information on how you generated a menu as there is more then one method available to you.

Comment: I used the standard menu which came with awesome. I installed it with apt-get install awesome

Comment: I do not know what "standard" that is in Ubuntu. Most people I know, myself included, write our own menus. My guess would be xdg menu. Until you know, you need to do a little reading on the link I gave you, look at your installed packages, read the Awesome documentation, and figure out how you generated a menu. Your other option is to wait of someone who uses ubuntu and awesome WM, might be a long wait as awesome is not as popular as other windows managers in the Ubuntu community.

Comment: I will start researching it.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the the menubar with the default keybinding "Mod4" + "p". The menubar lists more applications than the awesome/debian menu.